# Combine all of the elements from list of the lists

Tags: prolog

How can i combine all of the list elements from list in lists?

example

```
combine([[a,b,c],[d,[e,f],g],h],X).
return X = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

This is what i had try

```
flat([], []).
flat([First|Rest], _X):-
    flat(Rest, First).
```

Comment: You can also look for inspiration at the SWI-Prolog library implementation of `flatten/2`, which is the exact predicate that you are trying to implement: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src (search the page for the definition of flatten)

Comment: Isn't this just what the built-in `flatten` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively.

Define your base cases first - if you have no lists to combine you have an empty list.

```
combine([],[]).
```

and if you have a single element you have a singleton list

```
combine(X,[X]).
```

Then we define the general case - a non-empty list

```
combine([X|Xs], Y) :-
```

First we want to recursively flatten the head

```
combine(X,XX),
```

then the tail

```
combine(XS,XXs),
```

then we put these together

```
append(XX,XXs,Y).
```

We have to think carefully about how we put this together. The base case for the singleton element wants to appear last. When matching rules Prolog will match the first that applies - the base case with a singleton element will match a list, so we put this after this case to stop it matching in this case. Finally giving us:

```
combine([],[]).
combine([X|Xs],Y) :- combine(X,XX), combine(Xs,XXs), append(XX,XXs,Y).
combine(X,[X]).
```

Comment: That implementation seems rather inefficient. Did you tested it?

Comment: This is give me a lot of helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: btw, i did modify a little bit from your code. :P